# Getting null value for configuration/connection string

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have recently upgraded my project from dotnet core v.1.0.0 to v.1.0.4.  I am using the same code in each of the Startup.cs files.  V.1.0.0 works fine, .4 does not.  Visual Studio 2017.

```
System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at ApostilleDNCv2.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in c:\users\kenn.kinnaird\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ApostilleDNCv2\ApostilleDNCv2\Startup.cs:line 34
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.TypeActivatorCache.CreateInstance[TInstance](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type implementationType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ControllerContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
```

My code (both version):

Startup.cs-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApostillesTest")));
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
```

appsettings.json-

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "ApostillesTest": "Server=TESTSQLCORP;Database=Apostilles;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=True",
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=TESTSQLCORP;Database=Apostilles;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

}

I have looked at other solutions here; none have helped.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Found the answer.  Connection strings have to be first in the appsettings file.

Comment: I tried this, couldn't get it to work, I ended up just hard-coding the Connection String